# Applying isolated CSS to PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I've built my current site into a mashup of HTML & PHP. I originally embedded CSS to each individual page. I'm using a PHP include for the separate header & footer PHP files. I've linked the footer.php & header.php to their respective .css files, and it works to a degree, but it seems that CSS is "bleeding through" to both the header and footer PHP files.

For instance, I'll apply a dark gray to my body text & links to my footer.css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #808080;
}
a:link {
color: #808080 ;
}
a:visited {
color: #808080 ;
}
body {
background-image: url();
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color: #000000;
}
.style4 {font-size: 13px}
-->

#footer { width: 100%; height: 20%; background: #181818   ; }



//footer-nav style

#footer-nav {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
float: center;


}

#footer-nav li {
display: inline;


}

#footer-nav li a {
float: center;  
text-align: center;
background: none;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
height: 23px;
line-height: 23px;
}











</style>
```

`

This is then transferring over to my header.php file and changing the links to a dark gray (which shouldn't be happening as I'm linking header.php to it's own header.css file).

What I'm essentially trying to achieve is a dynamic header & footer linking system on my website so that I can easily update all headers & footers site-wide by replacing just one file in case of an added link, service, etc.

If there is a more efficient way of doing this please let me know!

Comment: Have you considered maybe storing the color values in a database and making the CSS in-line on each page?

Comment: ^That's a great idea. I'm not that advanced however! Would this then require that I create my own color code & referencing system in an additional web language?

Comment: No, not at all. It get's a little long (but not complicated) from here, so I'll direct you to w3schools.com. I would do a few of the PHP and MySQL tutorials, a little Googling, and some more questions here and you should be set ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically,  should only belong in the  of your page, not in inline blocks (though it does work).

You would need to change your CSS to select just the region you want to apply the styles to in each case. For example all the CSS for your header should be prefixed with your top level header element, #header.

Right now you are just styling top-level elements and the last  to load is taking effect.

Comment: ^That seems like it could be a solution - 

How would I then reference the #element in my CSS code?

For instance, I have li and div #elements but I don't know how to call out CSS styles like that.

Comment: So in your header let's say you have <div id="header"><ul><li><a href="#">Link</a></li></ul></div> you would add styles for #header ul, #header li and #header a, e.g. for orange links in header only, #header a { color: orange; }

Comment: So this would become additionally embedded CSS in the header.php file?


EDIT: Or, would I just add #header a #header li, etc.... to the header.css file?

Comment: Thanks sir! this got me on the right track. I can already see it working on my external .css files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting something like this on the background of the particular css.
Ex.

background: #181818 !important;